# Block certain ports on certain VMs running on KVM

Tags: firewall, kvm-virtualization, port, libvirt, virsh

I have 2 VMs Running on KVM hosts. I run a web server on one and use the other for experimental stuff - basically just use ssh on it.

I want to block all incoming connections on all ports except on port 80 on the web server VM and want to block all ports except a specific port which I use for ssh on the other VM.

I know I can use the iptables on the VMs themselves. But I want to do this using the KVM hosts. I want to do this for 2 major reasons,

- Going forward I might be handing the VMs to someone else.
- I might be adding more VMs and want to control the access from outside the VMs and not depend on the users of the VMs to handle it.

I have never done this and was trying out things.
I have been looking at `virsh` from [here](https://libvirt.org/firewall.html).

I was trying out the `The network filter driver` part.

I created a rule using the below xml to block all tcp ports between 0 and 1023,

```
<filter name='no-spamming' chain='root'>
  <uuid>d217f2d7-5a04-0e01-8b98-ec2743436b74</uuid>
  <rule action='drop' direction='in' priority='500'>
    <tcp match='yes' srcportstart='0' srcportend='1023'/>
  </rule>
</filter>
```

And then I used `virsh edit` and added the marked line in the xml.

```
<interface type='ethernet'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:33:b8:c7'/>
  <script path='no'/>
  <target dev='tap0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <filterref filter='no-spamming'/>       <-- Added this line
  <boot order='2'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Even After this I could access port 80 on both the VMs.

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong or suggest an alternative to `virsh` that can be used to achieve this please ?

### EDIT

I followed the suggestions in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/800134/block-certain-ports-on-certain-vms-running-on-kvm/800137#800137) answer and changed the `srcportstart` to `dstportstart` and `srcportend` to `dstportend`.

But I am still able to ssh on port 22 to both the VMs.

Comment: What's wrong with having a normal firewall on the VMs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter on destination port rather than source port and as such should be using `dstportstart`/`dstportstop` to filter incoming connections.

Comment: After I change the rules, do I have to reload them somehow ? Because after the changes, I am still able to access ssh :(